# Alert display after a method call

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I have the following code

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!AuthM.saveList}" id="saveButton" value="Save" onclick="nullDatePopup()"/>
        <script>
        function nullDatePopup(){
            var f='{!AuthM.flag}';
            if(f==1)
            alert("Hi");
        }
</script>
```

Here flag is a variable from the AuthM class. What I want is the alert to display after {!AuthM.saveList} method has been called and set the value of flag. But the alert is not showing at all. Can someone tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: ohh means once your method called i.e. `AuthM.saveList` after that display alert ?

Comment: @Ratan yes. that is exactly what I want

Answer (score 1):

Use `oncomplete` attribute.. It will call once first action completed.

So It will called after your controller method execution completed.

To get the update `{!AuthM.flag}` value. You need to rerender your javascript inorder to get updated value.

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!AuthM.saveList}" id="saveButton" value="Save" 
                                          oncomplete="nullDatePopup()" rerender="op1"/>

<apex:ouputPanel id="op1">
<script>
function nullDatePopup(){
      var f='{!AuthM.flag}';
      if(f==1)
      alert("Hi");
 }
 </script>
</apex:ouputPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You are calling your method on onClick which called just before the apex method call and never get true

You just need to do following :

```
  <apex:commandButton action="{!AuthM.saveList}" id="saveButton" value="Save" reRender="alertBlock"/>
<apex:outputPanel id="alertBlock">
<script>

    var f='{!AuthM.flag}';
    if(f==1)
    alert("Hi");

</script>
<apex:outputPanel>
```

OnComplete call will not work as it will call a already rendered javascript block which have old class values.

Comment: SFDC  Suppose your `<apex:outputPanel id="alertBlock">` inside your `<apex:page>` and you are trying to refresh your `<apex:page>`  then your your script will run again that will be unnecessary correct ?

Comment: If you need to apply check on updated value, you have to fetch them any how .

Comment: Yeah Yeah Correct.. Just saying it will be better option to use oncomplete attribute  to call javascript function instead each time run when you rerender outputpanel correct ?

Comment: When you call onComplete call, and want to check on some apex property value, you will always check on old values of ape until it is refreshed.

Comment: @SFDCGOD I tried your way. It is creating a different problem in the code.. Is it possible to give a javascript popup? Its extremely urgent

Comment: What is your problem now?